# What LEGO set do I have?

Tags: set-identification

I gave my father a LEGO set to help with his dementia. He lost the box and directions. I don't know what the set is. It appears to be a car. There is a windshield and some wheels. It's mostly black and red. It looks like only 2 bags. I know I didn't spend more than $15 on the kit.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! The items you have described are pretty common and it makes nearly impossible to identify the set. In order to help you we would like to have pictures added with as much elements as you can collect (partial assembly is also beneficial). We'll then try to identify less common or unique elements to use them for set identification.

Answer (score 19):

These parts are from:

[42089: Power Boat](https://brickset.com/sets/42089-1/Power-Boat)

[image]

Keypart : [62360 - Trans-Black Windscreen 3 x 6 x 1 Curved](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62360&idColor=13#T=C&C=13)